# libcurl on vps error

Tags: centos, vps

I've been trying to compile something, but, when running ./configure, it keeps spitting this out:
 configure: error: "libcurl 7.21 or later required"

I tried installing curl and libcurl 7.21 through RPMs I found on some sites, but it just drags me through a gigantic long cycle of dependencies.
 Is there any easy way to this?

Answer (score 0):

1. modify configure. f.e. 7.19 installed not far from 7.21 which is requirement.
2. make local copy of libcurl from source.